# How to control displaying submenu in css drop down menus?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've made a menu using CSS and UL,LI tags. The problem I have is that sometimes when I point the cursor on some menus that have submenus, and move it to point the displayed items, the new menu will be hide before I can hover the mouse pointer on them. In other word, submenu will be hide very fast.  How can I solve this problem?
You can see this menu at [www.parniaweb.ir](http://www.parniaweb.ir/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its an issue with the div styles below. Specifically the **top:38px;** value. If you set this to **top: 0px;** it will resolve the problem in chrome.

```
#cssmenu ul li > ul, #cssmenu ul li > div {
   display: none;
   width: auto;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   background: #333333;
   border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
   z-index: 999;
   border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

Comment: If I do it, the submenu will be opened on top of the main menu

Comment: what browsers are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of minor touches to your submenu's  element do the trick for me.  Take one pixel off the the "top" property (38 --> 37) and add a black border to the top to separate it from the other menu triggers.

```
#cssmenu ul li > ul, 
#cssmenu ul li > div {
    display: none;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 37px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #333;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    z-index: 999;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is just for 1 pixel, and what you said is something like `top:37px` instead of `38px`. And in this way, the problem will be solved.

Comment: Could you please mark your question as answered to tie this thread up?